# Combine two Active Model Serializers v 0.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I would like to do the same trick as in this post - https://thoughtbot.com/blog/fast-json-apis-in-rails-with-key-based-caches-and, but it is impossible to do in AMS 0.10.0.rc because AMS doesn't have a `#serializable_hash` method.

What would you suggest doing instead?

Answer (score 2):

Updated to the new version of `active_model_serializers` :

```
class BusinessDistanceSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :distance

  def attributes options = {}, reload = false
    data = super
    data.reverse_merge! ActiveModel::Serializer.adapter.new(BusinessSerializer.new(object)).serializable_hash
    data
  end

end
```

Notice the `reload = false` argument.

Comment: This is great, thanks.  Note that the syntax has changed to: `ActiveModelSerializers::Adapter.configured_adapter.new`

Answer (score 0):

This is how i'm doing it.

```
class BusinessDistanceSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :distance

  def attributes options = {}
    data = super
    data.reverse_merge! ActiveModel::Serializer.adapter.new(BusinessSerializer.new(object)).serializable_hash
    data
  end

end
```